# Nomenclature not working with automatic counter for entry sequence

Tags: counters, sorting, nomenclature, nomencl

I have a nomenclature for my file and I was trying to override the default sorting for the `nomencl` package using a custom counter, `indnom` but it's not working.

I want them in the order: A, Z, G, B

Here's the minimum working example which is compiled on `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\closenomencl}{%
    \closeout\@nomenclaturefile%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\writenomencl}[1]{%
    \closenomencl%
    \IfFileExists{#1.nlo}{%
        \write18{%
            makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o #1.nls -t #1.nlg #1.nlo%
        }% 
    }{\typeout{Nothing there}}%
}


\AtEndDocument{\writenomencl{\jobname}}
\newcounter{indnom}
\newcommand{\indnomout}{\refstepcounter{indnom}\theindnom}

\begin{document}

%% Specify nomenclature
\nomenclature[\indnomout]{A}{First entry}
\nomenclature[\indnomout]{Z}{Second entry}
\nomenclature[\indnomout]{G}{Third entry}
\nomenclature[\indnomout]{B}{Fourth entry}
    

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

What am I missing here?